# Wifi on my Dell doesn't work in Windows, after installing Crunchbang Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, wireless-networking, multi-boot, crunchbang

I installed Crunchbang Statler on my Dell Latitude E6400.

And ever since I did that, my wifi wouldn't work after I did a reboot from crunchbang, and booted into Windows 7, the other OS on the laptop.

I considered myself stupid for thinking that installing Crunchbang was the reason for this behaviour [until I found that there are other people who have experienced the same problem as well.](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/9464/strangest-thing-with-statler-installwifi-card-doesnt-work-in-windows/)

Any idea why this is happening? Wifi works when I shutdown, and then boot into Windows 7; it doesn't work when I do a reboot from Crunchbang.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like crunchbang is not powering off the adapter correctly. See if resetting the adapter, and enabling/disabling it again fixes the issue. Also, try just doing a shutdown from crunchbang, as opposed to a reboot (should be the same thing, but just to be extra careful...)